# Appium how to get adb logcat

Tags: java, logcat, appium

I was wondering if anybody knows a way that i can get the logcat while running automated tests using Appium for android mobile device. I'm using Java and I'm in a windows environment.

Any ideas? Thanks!!

Answer (score 13):

You can use this implementation:

```
List<LogEntry> logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get("logcat").getAll();
```

Before quitting the driver. Then just print the list to an external file.

The method will look something like that:

```
public static void captureLog(AppiumDriver driver, String testName)
    throws Exception {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy_HH-mm-ss");
    Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    String reportDate = df.format(today);
    String logPath = "C:\\automation_capture\\";
    log.info(driver.getSessionId() + ": Saving device log...");
    List<LogEntry> logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get("logcat").filter(Level.ALL);
    File logFile = new File(logPath + reportDate + "_" + testName + ".txt");
    PrintWriter log_file_writer = new PrintWriter(logFile);
    log_file_writer.println(logEntries );
    log_file_writer.flush();
    log.info(driver.getSessionId() + ": Saving device log - Done.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: I have added a function to my original post as an example.

Comment: you might want to add the specification of what `log` and `Level` are for.

Comment: Sure, you can find it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25457858/android-log-levels

Comment: @EyalSooliman can you please tell me how can i use **filter by tag name**? I need to get log of my app only.

Comment: @Subanunique: you can use this post (under section: 'Filtering log output') to might find your answer: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat#filteringOutput

Comment: do you know how to set the format within this code?

Answer (score 2):

**But be carefully!** Function *.getTimestamp()* for single LogEntry returns **incorrect value**

```
List<LogEntry> adbLogs = driver().manage().logs().get("logcat").filter(Level.ALL);
log.info("First timestamp: " + adbLogs.get(0).getTimestamp());
log.info("Last timestamp: " + adbLogs.get(adbLogs.size()-1).getTimestamp());
```

*Output (it's a bit formatted):*

First timestamp: 1 514 841 545 766

Last timestamp: 1 514 841 594 154

*A part of real logcat:*

1514841545767   **01-01 19:39:48**.570 bla-bla-bla-first-record

1514841594154   **01-01 23:19:53**.440 bla-bla-bla-last-record

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("//Users//.....//.....//android-sdk-macosx//platform-tools//adb logcat -d");
```