# How do I monitor iOS simulator/Android emulator's HTTP traffic from Appium JUnit tests?

Tags: java, android, ios, junit, appium

So I am writing JUnit tests for iOS/Android apps using Appium to drive the tests on an iOS simulator and Android emulator.  The app sends and receives HTTP calls to a remote server.  I would like to test that the app is sending the correct HTTP traffic from my JUnit tests.  What are some ways that I can monitor the network traffic from within my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue a few months back and tried two solutions for it.

1) Use a proxy in your code. I tried a little proxy. I kind of liked it but it increased my overhead for maintaining little proxy code as well. It works if you have extremely advanced knowledge with proxies; you will be able to handle it. https://github.com/ganskef/LittleProxy-mitm

2) I finally figured out it's best to use Android logcat. Whatever communication our phones do, everything gets logged in logcat. I just needed some commands to filter out the network requests that my App was making. I don't remember all of the commands but it's something like this. I know its not correct, but it will give you a headstart and I am 100% sure someone will correct this.

> adb logcat -d | grep com.xyz.abc

Comment: I've been looking into little proxy as well.  Filtering Android logcat seems like an easier solution.  Do you know if iOS has a logger that can be parsed for the HTTP traffic data as well?

Comment: you have two options for IOS iconsole  https://github.com/nicklockwood/iConsole and idevicesyslogs http://www.libimobiledevice.org/. Also you could send me 1000$ to get a working code for your project. :)

Comment: ah... I think I found a way.  I am getting the logs from the driver via driver.manage().logs().get("logcat") for Android and driver.manage().logs().get("syslog") for iOS

Comment: are you using Appium? if not then what are you using?

Comment: yes, I am using Appium.  I did something similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28557828/appium-how-to-get-adb-logcat

Answer (score 1):

For javascript and python the command is:

```
driver.getLogs('logcat');
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com)

[[Charles Proxy change response]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54516008/4770877)